# Lint for both TS and SCSS goes haywire

Tags: lint, tslint, csslint

I've used both Atom and Visual Studio Code, but in both the same thing always happens eventually:

Even though I'm not doing any updates in the app I'm using at the moment, just coding away (light frontend) as usual, suddenly without any warning the lint just goes haywire and starts warning me about errors that doesn't even exist. Recently it started warning me for files I haven't even touched about images and lack of CSS classes to be missing, but they aren't. They work and the code is 100% correct and have worked before. So I might get 10 various lint errors that are completely false mixed with lint errors that I actually need to fix. Or simply just lint errors that are false.

Again, this happens both in Atom and VSC and it just suddenly happens out of the blue, and this really stuns me. Any ideas why this is and how to correct it?

Comment: Which linter(s) are you using? What are the exact lint errors you're getting?

Comment: For instance, now I got:
{
 "resource": "[CENSORED]/src/components/Switch/index.tsx",
 "owner": "typescript",
 "code": "2339",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "Property 'switchComponent' does not exist on type 'typeof import(\"*.scss\")'.",
 "source": "ts",
 "startLineNumber": 47,
 "startColumn": 14,
 "endLineNumber": 47,
 "endColumn": 29
}"

and it refers to the stylesheet. But the stylesheet exists and the classes are there, and they are shown in the page. I'm using React btw.

Comment: I'm looking for patterns and it seems to happen when another genuine lint error happens, then it goes haywire. And forgot to say: I'm using TSLint and I guess the built in lint in VSCode.